# Can one use ma'aser money to pay for shipping a donation to charity?

Tags: halacha, tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes, mail

If one orders an item to donate to a charitable organization, such as a shul or Yeshiva, and wants to deduct the value of the item from his ma'aser money, can he deduct the shipping costs?

Does it make a difference if he could have picked the item up in the store and saved on shipping, but for his own convenience (or time constraints) chose not to?

Comment: It would seem logical, just as having any expenses would probably count as ma'aser. Perhaps even the stamps used to mail in a check is part of the ma'aser. It would not matter what you could have done, only what you actually did.

Comment: @ypnypn thanks - I'm particularly un-gifted at making titles.

Comment: Considering that ma'aser to begin with is not a real requirement, but rather a good practice, I don't see any reason why you wouldn't be able to do that...

Comment: @WhoKnows I assume you wouldn't use the same logic to say that you could toss it in to a lake. And sifri to devarim 14:22 implies it is a mitzvah.

Comment: @YEZ Theoretically, you can do with your money what you want... And we don't seem to hold like that Sifri halacha l'masei.

Comment: @WhoKnows seeing as to how there are entire sefarim written about hilchos maaser kesafim, it does "seem" that we hold it is more than just a nice thing.

Comment: @YEZ "Nice things" are very important, and it is very important to do them correctly. But we must remember hierarchy — in the grand scheme of things, maaser is not a Biblical commandment, nor even a Rabbinic one. That's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

If we generalize a bit I understand you are asking if expenses related to tzedakah count as tzedakah, with a subcase being when expenses are for the convenience of the donor.

[Eretz Hemda](https://eretzhemdah.org/qna.asp?lang=en&pageid=&cat=18) addresses a very similar scenario

> **For sure, the full amount [you spend which] counts. It is rare to give donations where
>   there are not costs in some form and usually there is no way to avoid
>   or to calculate how much.**
>
> In general, it is how much you spend on it.
>   For example, you can count toward maaser the stamp and envelope (if
>   you still send that way), even if I don't know I would suggest being
>   that exacting.

R Shimon Taub in [The laws of tzedakah and maaser](http://artscroll.com/Details.aspx?itemNo=LOTH) (p. 104) says **a charity collector is permitted to deduct from the tzedakah account any expenses that were incurred to enable the tzedakah fund to function**. I think the analogy holds here as well.